# Exporting Crystal Reports to PDF, is it possible to disable Save functionality

Tags: asp.net, pdf, crystal-reports

I am exporting a crsytalreport to pdf using asp.net.

On executing the report is opened in the default pdf reader(adobe reader 9 in my case) which is embedded in the browser (ie 8 in my case).

I need the report only to be viewed and to print and it should not be allowed to be saved.

I need a way to disable the save button in the tool bar of the pdf reader,browser and disable the right click in pdf reader.

Note: The print button should be left enabled

> Softwares used
>
> pdf reader :  adode reader 9 
>   browser    :  internet explorer 8 
>   platform   :  asp.net

Answer (score 2):

You can disable/enable certain operations on the PDF via encryption, but disabling the "Save A Copy" button isn't one of them.  The PDF is already on the client side at that point, and Adobe's browser plugin always has that feature enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can only hide the menu bar.

http://support.adobe.com/devsup/devsup.nsf/docs/51866.htm